# .NET Notification when a process has been killed

Tags: .net

My .NET application is starting a second process with
Process.Start(".\path\to\process.exe")
Is there a way to get notified when this process is killed by another process during the execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Exited` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) in the returned `Process` instance.

Comment: At first I forgot to set EnableRaisingEvent = True, but now it works! Thanks!